Custom TypeScript library import causes interference with Zone.js
I am working on a TypeScript project where I have a custom library that exports various services. The services are defined and exported in my
index.ts
file as shown below:
// Services
import { AITranslateService } from '@services/ai/ai-translate/ai-translate.service';
// ... other imports and exports

When I import any of these services into another library, they are being wrapped in a ZoneAwarePromise, which prevents me from using them as expected. Here is an example of how I am importing the services:
import { AITranslateService } from 'path-to-index-file';

Upon importing, the service is wrapped in a ZoneAwarePromise and I cannot use it directly. I suspect this issue is related to Angular's Zone.js library, which patches Promises to be zone-aware.
Questions:

Why are my services being wrapped in ZoneAwarePromise when imported?
How can I prevent Zone.js from interfering with my custom library imports?
Are there any best practices to avoid such issues when working with Angular and Zone.js?

Additional Information:
package.json:
{
  "name": "mylib",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "MyLib",
  "main": "dist/js/main.js",
  "types": "dist/@types/index.d.ts",
  "private": false,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "build:dev": "webpack --mode development",
    "publish-lib": "npm run build && npm publish",
    "publish-beta": "npm run build && npm publish --tag beta",
    "publish-dryrun": "npm run build && npm publish --dry-run"
  },
  "files": [
    "/dist"
  ],
  "peerDependencies": {
    "axios": "1.2.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "1.2.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@eslint/js": "^9.15.0",
    "@types/node": "^22.10.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint": "^9.15.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.2.1",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^4.2.0",
    "path-browserify": "^1.0.1",
    "prettier": "^3.4.1",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.10",
    "ts-loader": "^9.5.1",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "typescript-eslint": "^8.16.0",
    "webpack": "^5.96.1",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.10.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
}

tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es2019",
    "strict": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["node_modules/*"],
      "@services/*": ["src/services/*"],
      "@models/*": ["src/models/*"],
      "@utils/*": ["src/utils/*"],
      "@libs/*": ["src/libs/*"]
    },
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./src/@types"],
    "types": ["node"],
    "removeComments": true,
    "jsx": "react" // for react compatibility
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}

webpack.config.js:
const path = require('path');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer');
const ESLintPlugin = require('eslint-webpack-plugin');
const { ProgressPlugin } = require('webpack');
const DeclarationBundlerPlugin = require('./declaration-bundler-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
  const mode = argv.mode || 'production'; // Default to 'production' if mode is not provided

  return {
    mode: mode,
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.ts'),
    output: {
      filename: 'js/[name].js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      library: 'DcServices'
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
      alias: {
        '@services': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/services'),
        '@utils': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/utils'),
        '@libs': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/libs'),
        '@models': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/models')
      },
      fallback: {
        path: require.resolve('path-browserify'),
        fs: false
      }
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.ts$/,
          use: {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            options: {
              transpileOnly: mode === 'development' // Speed up development build
            }
          },
          exclude: /node_modules/
        }
      ]
    },
    optimization: {
      minimize: mode === 'production', // Minify only in production
      minimizer: [
        new TerserPlugin({
          terserOptions: {
            compress: {
              drop_console: mode === 'production' // Remove console logs in production
            }
          }
        })
      ],
      splitChunks: {
        chunks: 'all',
        automaticNameDelimiter: '-' // Makes chunk names more readable
      },
      usedExports: true, // Enable tree shaking
      sideEffects: true // Enable tree shaking
    },
    performance: {
      hints: mode === 'production' ? 'warning' : false, // Only show performance hints in production
      maxAssetSize: 300000, // Set the maximum asset size to 300 KiB
      maxEntrypointSize: 300000 // Set the maximum entry point size to 300 KiB
    },
    plugins: [
      new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
      // Only run BundleAnalyzerPlugin in production mode
      ...(mode === 'production' ? [new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({ analyzerMode: 'static', openAnalyzer: false })] : []),
      new ESLintPlugin({
        extensions: ['.js', '.ts'],
        exclude: 'node_modules',
        emitWarning: mode === 'development', // Emit warnings in development mode
        failOnError: mode === 'production' // Fail on errors in production mode
      }),
      new ProgressPlugin(),
      new DeclarationBundlerPlugin({
        out: './@types/index.d.ts',
        moduleName: 'index',
        mode: 'internal',
        excludedReferences: ['node_modules']
      })
    ],
    devtool: mode === 'development' ? 'source-map' : false // Enable source maps in development mode
  };
};

Any help or guidance on this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
